# How can I specify which data to load from database when I've passed multiple rows to a view in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I want to populate a view (headings, paragraphs, etc) using data from a database. Rather than pass in separate variables from the controller for each row, I've passed in every row in the database that applies to that particular view:

```
public function index()
{
   $all = Content::where('page', 'welcome')->get();
   return view('welcome')->with('all', $all);
}
```

The problem then is, when I go back to the view, I don't know how to load the correct data. I use

```
{{ $all }}
```

which, of course, loads every column and row in the database that has "welcome" in the "page" column.

I am wondering whether there's something like

```
{{ $all->where(id=1) }}
```

for example or something along those lines.

I don't want to use a @foreach loop because that will also load all the columns and I then have to filter out each one. Whereas, what I want to do is specify exactly which row to load and where to put it.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$all` is a collection of rows on which you can use collection helpers. In your case I'd suggest using the [where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where) method for that.

```
$all->where('id', 1);
```

Comment: Excellent. One thing missing though, when I use ->get('id') it returns null. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I think I've figured it out; I've used ->get(0)->id

Comment: And using ->first() is even better lol. Thanks for your help btw